# Can a macro be used for read-only access to a variable?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Can you define a macro that accesses a normal variable, but in a read-only fashion (other than defining it as a call to a function)? For example, can the VALUE macro in the following code be defined in such a way that the dostuff() function causes a compile error?

```
struct myobj {
  int value;
}

/* This macro does not satisfy the read-only requirement */
#define VALUE(o) (o)->value

/* This macro uses a function, unfortunately */
int getvalue(struct myobj *o) { return o->value; }
#define VALUE(o) getvalue(o)

void dostuff(struct myobj *foo) {
   printf("The value of foo is %d.\n", VALUE(foo)); /* OK */
   VALUE(foo) = 1; /* We want a compile error here */
   foo->value = 1; /* This is ok. */
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason const won't work for you?

Comment: The value isn't constant, but should be modified only in a limited number of places. This sort of macro would allow a policy of accessing via the macro, and help to minimize accidental modifications. It will also help ferret out legacy code that still changes the value, which is no longer desirable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the variable is always numeric, this works:

```
#define VALUE(x) (x+0)
```

or in the context of your example,

```
#define VALUE(x) (x->value+0)
```

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I came up with one:

```
#define VALUE(o) (1 ? (o)->value : 0)
```

Comment: I like yours too, because it works on non-numeric values just as easily.

Comment: Actually it may not, I think the type of data on both sides of the colon must be the same in the tertiary operator.  So if o->value is a struct, for example, I don't think this would work.  You could put (o)->value on both sides of the colon though.

Answer (score 6):

See §6.5.17 in the C standard (C99 & C1x): “A comma operator does not yield an lvalue.”

```
#define VALUE(x) (0, x)
```

(Not portable to C++.)

Comment: Note that this will work not just numeric types, but for `struct`s as well.  OTOH, in C++ the comma operator _does_ yield an lvalue, so it’s not portable that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#define VALUE(o) (const int)((o)->value)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this a puzzle or is it an engineering task?
If it's an engineering task, then there are better ways to get opacity of structures in C.  In [this blog article](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2008/07/02/how-to-build-a-managed-unmanaged-library.aspx), I wrote a decent enough description of how to do that in C.

Comment: It looks effective, but I was looking for something more quick-n-dirty. I have a specific application in mind for this. It won't be as rock solid as a managed library, but there is limited time for development.

Comment: It's not so much the managed/unmanaged bit, it's the public opaque struct and API combined with a private open struct.  This is the standard C trick to hide data to a client of an API.  If you're using C++ you would obviously use a class.